# Why the minimal footage of a Succah is not mentioned in the Mishnah?

Tags: mishna, shiurim-measurements, sukkah, masechet-sukkah

The first Mishnah in Succah discusses the height of Schach but not the measures. Subsequently, the Mishnah does not deal with it at all (*[Mishna 2.7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sukkah.2.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) discusses the placement of the table independently of the size of the Succah*)

Why does the Mishnah omit such a fundamental Halacha?

N.b. the Halacha is finally derived by the Gemmorah, but the question is why not by the Mishnah?

Comment: Is there really any minimum length or width other than being able to "dwell" in it? I recall years ago, a few people built a "Superman booth" succah. Barely fit one person.

Comment: @DanF Definitely as there are numerous arguments whether it should be 4*4 Amah like a minimum apartment or under 10 Tfachim is called Dira Srucha.

Comment: ??? 4*4 and 10? Minimum is 7*7.

Comment: @Danny according to some Rishonim. Maybe if people nowadays have bigger heads on average then the application of Rosho veRubbo changes to 8x8.